# Estimating for atomic number for an "unknown element"

Tags: isotope

A questions tells me there's this element with 3 isotopes (270.51 amu, 34.07% abundance; 271.23 amu, 55.12%; and 269.14 amu, 10.81%), and to solve for average atomic mass. I have done so and got 271 (270.758) for its atomic mass. Then it asks me to estimate its atomic number, and its location on the periodic table. How do I exactly "estimate"?

ps. I dont think this element actually exists...

Comment: Note that, in general chemistry, the atomic mass unit (amu), which referred to the atomic mass of oxygen, is obsolete since 1961.

Comment: You need at least four significant figures not 3 for the average atomic weight, but I'd give 5 in this case. // I know that there is some curve relating atomic number and atomic weight but I can't remember the name right now. // Peeking at the periodic table, Sg with atomic number 106 seems to fit.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula#Examples_for_consequences_of_the_formula the curve is shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve

Comment: @MaxW there is also a good atomic number vs. atomic weight answer here on chem.se: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32158/is-there-a-function-to-approximate-atomic-mass-from-the-atomic-number/32159#32159

Comment: @ph13 - Thanks for the link! I upvoted Geoff's answer. I'm sure he wasn't the first to play with the equations, but he gave a really good answer. // It doesn't seem that the power law equation has a particular name which somewhat surprises me.

Answer (score -2):

Well I found it out. It is seaborgium atomic number 106, mass number 271.

To be found in period B6, group 7.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. At the moment this reads more like a comment than an actual answer - could you elaborate a little more, for example **how** you found it, because that is the actual question. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) on any question/answer.